# Capybara: simple way to find elements without particular text

Tags: capybara

There are several elements on the page, and I need an array of them, but without an element with particular text. What I do now is

```
tabs_quantity = page.all(:css, 'div.class1 ul.tabs li.tab.exist', visible: true)
tabs_quantity.each { |x|
  if x.text != 'Main'
    ...blah-blah-blah...
```

I`ve seen only ":text => 'Text' everywhere but what I need is opposite to equality, so I've searched and tested but have not find if there is something simple like

```
tabs_quantity = page.all(:css, 'div.class1 ul.tabs li.tab.exist', visible: true, :text !=> //or "not equal", whatever// 'Main')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Raza.  Definitely try to **set a class on the elements** you're looking for.

If that turns out to be impossible for whatever reason, here are a couple more options.

1) You could try regular expressions:

```
# match text that doesn't contain 'Main'
page.all('li.tab.exist', text: /^(?:(?!Main).)*$/)
```

That's not super easy to read.  But since you've scoped your class down quite a bit, it might not be too slow.

2) Another alternative is xpath:

```
# find li with class of 'exist' and any text except 'Main'
page.all(:xpath, "//li[contains(@class, 'exist') and not(contains(.,'Main'))]" )
```

That's also a bit unweildy, especially if you want to go as in depth as your original css matcher.  I'd definitely include a comment along with it.

Further info: using a css class is definitely faster and easier.  Always avoid text matches whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, xpath seems to be just what I need. I thought about regexp too, but xpath is way easier to read and to review when there is no opportunity to change the code and to set a class.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to the group of elements you want to select and the find with:

```
page.find('.class_name')
```

Comment: Do you have any common attribute in those filed you want to select ?

Comment: I do not think so, and the attributes can change.